# Set the value of one property to the value of property containing a primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using C# Entity Framework. I have constructed the following properties as follows:

```
private int _CashTransactNO;

[DatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CashId { get; set; }

public int CashTransactNO
{
    get { return _CashTransactNO; }
    set
    {
        _CashTransactNO = CashId;
    }
}
```

When I run the windows form application. 'CashTransactNO' always returns a value of zero and not the primary key generated from 'CashId'
Any ideas how to work this out so I can pass the incrementing key value to 'CashTransactNO and save in the MSSQL database?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just return CashId in the getter of CashTransactNO, and remove the private setter?

Comment: Also...are you calling the private setter? I don't see it in the code above and that must be called in order to change the value to anything other than zero.

Comment: What's the bigger picture that makes doing this necessary?

Comment: A setter that just swallows its entered `value` is... crazy. For the rest you're probably just experiencing that `CashId` is not assigned before `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `public int CashId { get; set; }` to:

```
private int _CashId;
[DatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CashId {
    get
    {
         return _CashId;
    }
    set
    {
         _CashId = value;
         CashTransactNO = _CashId;
    }
}
```

and then you can leave your `CashTransactNO` like:

`public int CashTransactNO { get; private set; }`

No need for the `_CashTransactNO`.

Comment: Tried this as well the value of cashId is reflected in the CashTransact property but the value in the database is still zero. All other properties in the same class are updating their values as expected in the SaveChages() method in EF but the Transact Column in database is  zero!

Comment: @RobertOmete you should update your question to include the detail that you want to save `CashTransactNO` in the database.

Comment: @DavidSherret You are right.The bigger picture is that since I am unable to make a function in C# that auto-increments when an insert is made it would be better to base it on an existing Id column instead

Answer (score 0):

The primary key name in Entity Frameworks  is either `ID` or `classnameID`. When you do `[DatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, it automatically increments from 1 as primary key cannot be zero. If you have any other naming convention for the Primary Key you can use `[key]` attribute to make It a primary key or change the naming convention. I guess here the `_Cashid` is not being identified as a primary key so it can be null so it increments with zero. I hope this helps to solve the problem.